# Правило для изменения URL. 2 переменные

Tags: .htaccess

Всем привет.

Толи я стал слишком стар, толи что.. не могу разобраться с ЧПУ.

```
// .htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+).html$ index.php?menu=$1&cont=$2

// адреса на сайте следующее
index.php?menu=1&cont=1 - охота видеть index.php/1/1.html
index.php?menu=2&cont=1 - охота видеть index.php/2/1.html
index.php?menu=3&cont=1 - охота видеть index.php/3/1.html
index.php?menu=4&cont=1 - охота видеть index.php/4/1.html
index.php?menu=1&cont=2 - охота видеть index.php/1/2.html
index.php?menu=2&cont=2 - охота видеть index.php/2/2.html
index.php?menu=3&cont=2 - охота видеть index.php/3/2.html
index.php?menu=4&cont=2 - охота видеть index.php/4/2.html
и т.п.
```

Подскажите, как правильно написать (переписать имеющийся) .htaccess ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?menu=$1&cont=$2 [L]
```