# Полный пример файла htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Доброго всем дня

Может ли кто поделиться файлом, или привести пример кода .htaccess, ВСЕГО файла, на котором точно можно проверить работает ли замена урл ( чпу в htaccess ) на сайте?

Ситуация такая. Устанавливаем чужое - работает (Joomla/Wordpress) . Делаем сами - нет. в моем случае не работает даже простая конструкция [Даже такая](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/143458/htaccess-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BB-2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?menu=$1&cont=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте официальную документацию:

- [Apache Wiki RewriteRule](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteRule)
- [Документация](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/)

Comment: Можно было еще дать ссылку на гуголь. Я сделал выше написанное с помощью справки + добавил 1 букву в конец по совету здесь. В причине не работоспособности этого вода и хотел получить здесь совет.

Comment: Ваш пример работает у меня без проблем. Проверьте подключен ли модуль mod_rewrite у apache, что тут можно посоветовать.

Пишите хоть, не работает - это как? Что происходит? Ошибки-то какие?

Comment: Уважаемый gridsane, пример который я привел у меня не работает. Ошибок никаких нет. То, что вы сказали, для меня тоже информация. Я чуть позже поставлю галку, что принимаю ответ. Хотел узнать, может есть что то еще, из за чего не работает этот код. (движки на этом же хостинге Joomla/Wordpress - работают, и как то делают изменение адреса, т.е. реврайт)

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` является подобием `httpd.conf` с той разницей, что действует только на каталог, в котором располагается, и на его дочерние каталоги. Возможность использования .htaccess в том или ином каталоге указывается в httpd.conf (директива `AllowOverride`).